# In Android how to add a view at particular x-y co-ordinates on the screen

Tags: android, layout, view

This is what I want to achieve. When ever a user taps at any point on the screen, I would like to show an image at that point for say 2 seconds. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to inform that, I finally achieved this by overriding the onDraw method and drawing it at the specified co-ordinates

Answer (score 0):

you can use Absolute layout but it is deprecated and not recommended to use because it won't give the same reults with different screen resolutions

http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/absolute-layout.html

you can check the relative layout as a substitute

http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/absolute-layout.html

thanks